# Allow access to specific user only (Postgres)

Tags: postgresql

I have a database with an owner for it. My problem is that, though i have assigned a password for the owner, any other db user can access this database locally, even without password.

How can i configure the database so that only a specific user has access to it (only with right password)?

Comment: This is more of a DBA question. See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17790/created-user-can-access-all-databases-in-postgresql-without-any-grants

Comment: @ChrisHeald Thanks. Moved my question to the DBA site. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/228282/allow-access-to-specific-user-only-postgres